# How to access module state inside store's getter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

/store/modules/mobile.js

```
export default {
  state: {
    names: []
  },

  mutations: {
    setKeystore (state, name) {
      state.names.push(name)
  },
```

/store/index.js

```
getters: {
  identities => ()=> names
```

After the mutation in module has been called, then the getter `identities` will be called. Now, identities getter gives empty array. However, if I try to access it using Vue dev tools, `$vm0.$store.$state.mobile.names`, I can find a non-empty array.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here in javascript part? If not, how can I access the module state inside getter in index.js?

Comment: This is not Php, the syntax in objects literal is: `key: value`, in this case, `identities: (state) => state.names`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [getters receive the state](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) of the Store as a parameter, you should use that to return the needed property, something like:

```
getters: {
  identities => (state)=> state.names
```